# Include script in template_redirect page

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

I'm writting a plugin and on this must generate a suggest page, the suggest I generate with template_redirect, like so:

```
add_action('template_redirect', 'suggest_page');

function suggest_page() {
  if (!preg_match('/suggest\.php$/', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']))
    return;

...
}
```

I'm wanting to include jQuery on this page, i konw that can use `wp_head();` just before `</head>` and then use `wp_enqueue_script('jquery');` but the `wp_head();` includes a lot of stuff that i don't need.

so there's a way to add a wordpress script to a page without include all head stuff of wordpress ?

Comment: I should have asked for clarifications before taking the time to answer. **What exactly do you mean** by *`a lot of stuff that I don't need`*?

Answer (score 0):

from the [template_redirect](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/template_redirect#Loading_a_template_from_a_plugin) codex, loading a template from a plugin. have you tried this